# The constructor to deserialize an object of Type was not found in derived class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Base class does not contain no argument constructor and is not serializable. so i tried this:
[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xacVd.png)

On Deserialization, Exception caught:
The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'ProjectHttpClientEx' was not found.
I am using Binary serialization/deserialization
[Serial/Deserial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3EQk.png)

How to fix it for deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing ISerializable you need to add a protected constructor taking a SerializationInfo and a StreamingContext and construct the members from there.

Implement GetObjectData to serialize the members
Add a protected constructor to deserialize the members and construct the object

```
protected ProjectHttpClientEx(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  member = info.GetBoolean("somedata"); // or empty
}

[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  info.AddValue("somedata", true);
}
```